# nuxt3 component keeping input value after derendering

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have an application where I pass information in components to be sent to the database... after sending I use v-if to hide this component, but when opening this component again the values ​​passed in the previous inputs appear again in this new component, as we having a memory leak, even if I destroy this component and render it again! I'm using nuxt3 and this same code worked perfectly on nuxt2

Comment: Just a drive-by comment. Even if you hide the component but you don't clear the variables (v-model) the component uses then wouldn't the component initialize with the old data?

Comment: im not using v-model, they are common input fields where by queryselector i just collect the input. in nuxt2 the default behavior was to clear these fields on component initialization.

Comment: i solved the problem by clearing the fields at startup, but i would like to know if there is a way to keep the same behavior as nuxt2 in nuxt3